# How to join these tables based on date range

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have 2 tables: Saleorder and Material as at the bottom,

the table Saleorder:

```
Saleorder    Datecreated    Material
A                2016-01-01      M1
B                2016-01-21      M1
C               2016-03-01       M1
```

and Material:

```
Material    Changedon    Materialresponsible
M1            2016-01-01        E
M1            2016-01-20        F
M1            2016-02-26       G
```

now i want to join table Saleorder with table Material based on Material and the Datecreated and changeondate, i would like to have the result like this:

```
Saleorder    Datecreated    Material    materialresponsible
A                2016-01-01      M1              E
B                2016-01-21      M1              F
C               2016-03-01       M1              G
```

The logic for the relation between Datecreated and Changedon date is:

-Order A was created on 1.1.2016, on that day the metarial M1 with materialresponsible E were valid.

-Order B was created on 21.01, but the metarial M1 has change on20.01, so the Materialresponsible F was valid

-order C was created on 01.03,but the Material M1 has changed on 26.02, so the Materialresponsible G was valid

Can you please help me how to do that?

Thanks

---

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Saleorder1](
    [Saleorder] nvarchar (20) NULL,
    [Datecreated] date NULL,
    [Material]  nvarchar (20) NULL,    )
INSERT INTO Saleorder1 (Saleorder,Datecreated,Material)
VALUES ('A','2016-01-01','M1'),
('B','2016.01.21','M1'),
('C','2016.03.01','M1')


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Material2](
    [Material] nvarchar(20) NULL,
    [Changedon] date NULL,
    [Materialresponsible]  nvarchar(20) NULL,)
INSERT INTO Material2
VALUES ('M1','2016-01-01','E'),
('M1','2016-01-20','F'),
('M1','2016-02-26','G')
```

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: which DBMS? MySQL or SQL Server? Unlikely to be both... And what have you tried so far? A join with multiple conditions, for instance?

Comment: Is there any criteria for sales created data and material change data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, You can use LEAD function to get above Result

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Saleorder1(
[Saleorder] nvarchar (20) NULL,
[Datecreated] date NULL,
[Material]  nvarchar (20) NULL,    )


INSERT INTO #Saleorder1 (Saleorder,Datecreated,Material)
VALUES ('A','2016-01-01','M1'),
('B','2016.01.21','M1'),
('C','2016.03.01','M1')


CREATE TABLE #Material2(
[Material] nvarchar(20) NULL,
[Changedon] date NULL,
[Materialresponsible]  nvarchar(20) NULL,)

INSERT INTO #Material2
VALUES ('M1','2016-01-01','E'),
('M1','2016-01-20','F'),
('M1','2016-02-26','G')
```

Now do Select with `LEAD` function like below

```
SELECT S.Saleorder, S.Datecreated, M.Material,M.Materialresponsible 
FROM #Saleorder1 S
INNER JOIN (

SELECT Material ,Changedon  ,Materialresponsible
,ISNULL( LEAD(Changedon) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),GETDATE()) Changedon_To_Dte  
FROM #Material2

)M ON S.Material = M.Material 
AND S.Datecreated BETWEEN M.Changedon AND M.Changedon_To_Dte
```

And the result will be

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+---------------------+
| Saleorder | Datecreated | Material | Materialresponsible |
+-----------+-------------+----------+---------------------+
| A         | 2016-01-01  | M1       | E                   |
| B         | 2016-01-21  | M1       | F                   |
| C         | 2016-03-01  | M1       | G                   |
+-----------+-------------+----------+---------------------+
```

And If you are using **Lower version** of SQL Server.

```
--CTE for SNO Generation
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) SNO
,Material,Changedon,Materialresponsible 
FROM #Material2
)

--CTE2 for generating Changedon_To_Dte by SELF Joining
,CTE2 AS (
SELECT C1.Material,C1.Changedon,C1.Materialresponsible
, ISNULL(C2.Changedon, GETDATE()) AS Changedon_To_Dte
FROM CTE C1
LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.SNO+1 = C2.SNO 
)

SELECT S.Saleorder, S.Datecreated, C2.Material,C2.Materialresponsible  
FROM #Saleorder1 S
INNER JOIN CTE2 C2 ON S.Material = C2.Material 
AND S.Datecreated BETWEEN C2.Changedon AND C2.Changedon_To_Dte
```